# Why is my function not calling itself again when it is finished (recursion)?

Tags: c

I currently finished my code. but for some reason my recursive call at the end isn't being triggered? Is there some sort of special code I am missing from this by chance?

```
int max(int arr[], int start, int end) {    
        int greatest = arr[start];
        if(start < end)
        {

        if(greatest<arr[start])
        {
            greatest = arr[start];
        }
        start++;
        max(arr, start, end); // Doesn't seem to be triggering since it only returns 8
        }   
        return greatest;
}       

int main()
{
     int greatest;
     int arr[10] = {8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
     int start = 0;
     int end = 10;
     greatest=max(arr, start, end);

     pintf("%d\n", greatest);

}
```

Comment: You need to copy-and-paste your *exact* code into the question. By re-typing it, you've introduced a typo (`pintf` for `printf`). We can't guess what other differences there might be between the code in your question and the code that you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is a little messed up. For instance, `greatest<arr[start]` will never be true, because you just set `greatest = arr[start]`. Here's a commented working algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
    if ( start >= end ) {

        /*  Shouldn't get here, but return 0 if we do  */

        return 0;
    }
    else if ( end - start == 1 ) {

        /*  Only one element, so it's the maximum by definiton  */

        return arr[start];
    }
    else {

        /*  Find the maximum of the rest of the list...  */

        int greatest = max(arr, start + 1, end);

        /*  ...and return the greater of it, and the first element  */

        return arr[start] > greatest ? arr[start] : greatest;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = { 8, 1, 2, 3, 12, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int start = 0;
    int end = 10;
    int greatest = max(arr, start, end);

    printf("%d\n", greatest);
}
```

with output:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$ ./max
12
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$
```

Let's go through it with a simple list, {1, 5, 3}. Each indentation level represents one of your recursive function calls. Every time we see `max()`, we go up a level - every time we see `return`, we go back a level.

```
In main(), int greatest = max(list, 0, 3)

    In call 1: (end - start == 1) is false
    In call 1: int greatest = max(list, 1, 3)

        In call 2: (end - start == 1) is false
        In call 2: int greatest = max(list, 2, 3)

             In call 3: (end - start == 1) is true
             In call 3: return arr[2], which is 3 

        Back in call 2: greatest now equals 3
        Back in call 2: arr[1] == 5, which is > 3, so return arr[1], which is 5

    Back in call 1: greatest now equals 5
    Back in call 1: arr[0] == 1, which is not > 5, so return greatest, which is 5

Back in main(), greatest now equals 5
```

Remember, every time you see `int greatest`, that's a *different* variable that's being created. They all have the same name, but since they're all in separate scopes, they're still all different. The `int greatest` in call 2, for instance, is completely separate from the `int greatest` in call 1, just as the `int greatest` in call 1 is completely separate from the `int greatest` in `main()`.

EDIT: From the comments, if you want the index of the maximum value as well, this'll do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max_index(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
    if ( start >= end ) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ( end - start == 1 ) {
        return start;
    }
    else {
        int greatest = max_index(arr, start + 1, end);
        return arr[start] > arr[greatest] ? start : greatest;
    }
}

int max(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
    if ( start >= end ) {

        /*  Shouldn't get here, but return 0 if we do  */

        return 0;
    }
    else if ( end - start == 1 ) {

        /*  Only one element, so it's the maximum by definiton  */

        return arr[start];
    }
    else {

        /*  Find the maximum of the rest of the list...  */

        int greatest = max(arr, start + 1, end);

        /*  ...and return the greater of it, and the first element  */

        return arr[start] > greatest ? arr[start] : greatest;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = { 8, 1, 2, 3, 12, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int start = 0;
    int end = 10;
    int greatest = max(arr, start, end);
    int index = max_index(arr, start, end);

    printf("Greatest value is %d at index %d\n", greatest, index);
}
```

output:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$ ./max
Greatest value is 12 at index 4
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$
```

Comment: Won't it be true  the second time around when I increment start by 1?

Comment: No, because you'll assign `arr[start]` to `greatest` again. That'll happen every time you call the function, not just the first time.

Comment: Sorry but,f or here you wrote return arr[start] > greatest ? arr[start] : greatest; what does the question mark do?

Comment: When you're dealing with recursion, as @Leushenko suggested, your function has no idea if it's been called before, it's going to act as if it's the first time it's ever been run.

Comment: @BeginnerC: It's just shorthand for `if ( arr[start] > greatest ) { return arr[start]; } else { return greatest; }`. It's called the ternary, or conditional operator, if you have `condition ? 1 : 2` the whole thing will evaluate to `1` if `condition` is true, and to `2` if `condition` is false.

Comment: Should that be before the the call to the function? If you call the function, doesn't it skip the return arr[start] > greatest ? arr[start] : greatest;?

Comment: @BeginnerC: No, because when you call the function, at some point it's going to return. When it does, that line will be the next thing to run. You'll end up calling `max()` a total of ten times. On the tenth time, it'll return `arr[9]` because `end - start == 1` will be true. Then it'll return, and `return arr[start] > greatest ? arr[start] : greatest;` will be executed in your ninth function call. Then *that* will return, and `return arr[start] > greatest ? arr[start] : greatest;` will be executed in your eighth function call. Then *that* will return....and so on until you're all done.

Comment: @BeginnerC: I've added an illustration of what's going on to the end of my answer, to help you visualize it a bit better.

Comment: Alright, it will tak me a while, but bear with me here

Comment: @BeginnerC: Don't worry, recursion seems to be hard for a lot of people to grasp, so you're not alone. It'll sink in eventually if you keep at it.

Comment: It seems that once we reach the condition of end - start == 1 it starts to unwind backwards and activates the arr[start] > greatest ?.. statement. When I think of this logically, I don't understand how that statement could be activating.

Comment: What I mean is that, the statement return arr[start] > greatest ? arr[start] : greatest activates after the else if statement is true. I just can't grasp the idea of how it even activates even though i UNDERSTAND the concept of how it will have to eventually run in the end. C logic is very confusing.

Comment: @BeginnerC: Essentially, because that line only activates once the recursive call to `max()` returns, and they'll only start returning once `end - start == 1` has evaluated to true in *one* of the calls (by necessity, the *last* call in the chain), because then it will just return, it won't call `max()` again. At that point, everything will start unwinding, `max()` will start returning, and in each of the *previous* calls the `return arr[start] > greatest ? arr[start] : greatest` line will run and you'll eventually end up back in `main()`.

Comment: Every time you recursively call `max()`, you're increasing `start` by `1`, but you're not increasing `end`, so with every call `end - start == 1` is getting closer and closer to being true. Eventually you'll call `max()` with `start` being just `1` less than `end`, that condition will then trip, and you'll start unwinding. The key with recursion is that there has to be a condition where the chain of calls will eventually end, and when it does, everything starts to unwind. Remember, every call to `max()` gets a different value of `start`.

Comment: Alright, thank you a lot for your help! I will now attempt to see if I can get this to return the index of largest element, instead of the element itself, just for the fun of it.

Comment: That's the spirit. As a hint, `return arr[start] > arr[greatest] ? start : greatest;` will be involved somewhere in there.

Comment: Sorry to get your hopes up, but I failed miserably >.<

Comment: Would it be possible to show me how we would accomplish this? I was thinking that we could return 2 things where one would be "start". But that won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Only the first call to `max` - the one located in `main` - actually assigns its return value to anything. The values returned by the recursive calls are immediately lost; the work they do is meaningless to the end result. You need to assign the result of the recursive call to `max` to `greatest`.

Remember that each recursive call opens up a new scope, each with its own version of the `greatest` variable. The assignments within each recursive call only modify their version of the variable, not the one from the enclosing scope; this means that the version from the very first call is never set to anything after taking the value of `arr[0]`; and that's the version whose value is returned to `main` when the outermost call resumes, regardless of the work done in between by the recursive calls.

You also have an unrelated error, which is that you recurse into another call to `max` (and assign to `greatest` within that call) *before* checking whether you've reached the end of the array, which will overflow beyond the end of the array and overwrite the final result with whatever is found there (as Paul points out, you also assign to `greatest` before making the comparison against the current value, so the comparison is essentially meaningless). You need to move everything inside the checks to make sure this doesn't occur.

Comment: I can't seem to wrap my head around giving the result of the recursive call to max to greatest.

Comment: Aren't I already do that when I do greatest = arr[start]? Sorry I am just so confused right now...

Comment: @BeginnerC that literally means the recursive call should be written `greatest=max(...`, the same as it appears in `main`. It sounds like you aren't fully grasping the role of variable scope and recursion? Each nested call to a function has its own set of copies of all of the local variables - imagine them as `greatest{0}`, `greatest{1}`, etc. Assigning to `greatest{1}` does nothing to `greatest{0}` which is left in the same state it was before the recursive call.

Comment: When I try your suggestion, I end up getting 0 now and yes I seem to be a little shaky on the the scopes, but I get what you mean as each new call creates a new local scope or such right? However, as I stated, when I change it to greatest=max(... in my function it gives me 0 now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the recursive call **is** being triggered, but isn't doing what you want. you initialize greatest to arr[start] (in this case 8), and never assign anything else to it, so of course your function is returning 8. Instead, it seems like your function should return arr[start] if start >= end, and otherwise should return either arr[start] or max(arr, start+1, end), whichever is larger.